# List Categories and articles in Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I'm trying to build a site with multiple categories and sub-categories in Joomla. The structure looks like this:

category 1
category 2
 - category 3
 - category 4
category 5
 - category 6
 - category 7
...

Each category has some articles.

What I want to do is create a navigation menu from these categories, so category 1,2,5 become top level links in the menu, while 3,4,6,7 become sub links in the corresponding dropdown list. **(Update)*And the articles under a category become sub links after the categories.***

I've tried a few options:
**Module Articles Category:** It lays out all articles in a flat list without categories, not good
**Module Articles Categories:** It lays out all the sub-categories, but no articles
**Menu item - List all categories:** It gives the right result, but in a page accessed by clicking that menu item.
**Menu item - single article:** It's totally static and time consuming.

I'm wondering if there's a way of generating an ordinary normal navigation menu, like the ones you see in Amazon or ebay?

Comment: You want the individual articles to be part of the navigation menu?

Comment: Yeah, and there're not so many to make the menu look overwhelming... But there're enough to make it difficult to input and manage, if done statically.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a menu structure that is similar to your category structure. So:

- Menu 1 corresponds to category 1
- Menu 2 corresponds to category 2
- Menu 2.1 etc

You can then link each menu item through a category blog type menu item to the appropriate category. You can then configure how the articles should be displayed (multi-column, intro etc).

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, I need the articles under a category become sub links after the categories

Comment: I guess you should have look at some extensions that might do the job. You might find something here: http://www.derosetechnologies.com/community/joomla-automatic-menu-magic